# Converting English to Ubbi Dubbi

Tags: java, eclipse

Hey guys i have to make a a application that converts UbbiDubbi to English. I am going to start out by explaining UbbiDubbi its not the normal way UbbiDubbi works, instead we are only adding ub in front of a vowel or a vowel cluster (cluster being no more then 2 vowels together). I almost have it im stuck on two parts  oneit will add the first vowel but not any other vowels in the String/Word. and two it runs the program over and over.

```
 public static String translateFromEnglish(String phrase) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("type in a phrase you would like to convert to Ubbi Dubbi");
         phrase = scan.nextLine();
        String Emptystring = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'a' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'e' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'i' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'o' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'u') {
            Emptystring += "ub";
            Emptystring += phrase.charAt(i);
            // +ub 
            // +a
            if (phrase.charAt(i+1) == 'a'){
                Emptystring += phrase.charAt(i+1);
                // +a
                // i +1
                } else {
                    if (phrase.charAt(i+1) == 'e') {
                        Emptystring += phrase.charAt(i+1);
                    }
                }
                        if (phrase.charAt(i+1) == 'i'){
                            Emptystring += phrase.charAt(i+1);
                    }else {
                        if (phrase.charAt(i+1) == 'o'){
                            Emptystring += phrase.charAt(i+1);
                            }
                    }
                        if (phrase.charAt(i+1) == 'u') {
                            Emptystring += phrase.charAt(i+1);
                            } 


        }
                        else {
                            Emptystring += phrase.charAt(i);

                        }

        // here i am check to see if the String contains any vowels or vowel
        // clusters

        // here i printed out the new word



        }
        System.out.println(Emptystring);    


        return phrase;  
    }
```

Console
type in a phrase you would like to convert to Ubbi Dubbi
Hello
your new Phrase is Hell 
error

Comment: don't have much time to help today - have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Please, **_PLEASE_** don't use `+=` on strings, instead use a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is hard to follow because of all of those if/else checks.
But when you write something like that `if (phrase.charAt(i+1) ==...` then you check only the next letter and not all the "vowels cluster" (which might lead to unecessary "ub"s). also when `i` will be the last iteration `i+1` will not be an index in the string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    static boolean isVowel(char v) {
         if (v == 'a' || v == 'e' || v == 'i' || v == 'o' || v == 'u') {
             return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("type in a phrase you would like to convert to Ubbi Dubbi");

        String phrase = scan.nextLine();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean prevVowel = false; //is our vowel part of a cluster?

        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        if (isVowel(phrase.charAt(i))) {
            if(prevVowel==false)
                result.append("ub");

            prevVowel=true;
        }
        else
            prevVowel=false;
        result.append(phrase.charAt(i)); //should be added anyway

        }
        System.out.println(result);    

    }
}
```

Comment: done. do you think it's okay to leave the constructor like that?